# Chess OS X Catalina Game Connected but Moves not Updating

Tags: mac, icloud, games, game-center

I am trying to play a Game Center Chess game on the Mac OS X Chess app with a friend who is also on OS X.

So far, we've been able to connect to each other to start a new game and at the top of the window it says I'm vs. Him in the game details, however , when he makes a move it doesn't update on my screen.

If one of us forfeits the game then the other can see they won so it updates that info.

The problem is our moves aren't updated as we're playing even though it says we are connected and playing against each other in the details of the window as a Game Center match.

Other info:
We are friends on Game Center on iOS and Mac

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing the same thing. I have been testing this out locally with two computers and two gamecenter accounts (both on High Sierra).  I see one game that says "Black to Move", while the other says "White To Move".

I have found one way to force an update is to go to the menu and choose Game -> Close, and then Game -> New -> GameCenter -> Start, and then it will show existing game center games, and you can choose to have your turn. Pretty annoying though.